# Flutter Delete all data in sqlite table, then insert records

Tags: sqlite, asynchronous, flutter

```
static Future<void> cleanDatabase() async {
    try{
      var start = 'delete from ';
      final db = await database();
      db.execute(start + AccountNames.tableName);
      db.execute(start + CategoryNames.tableName);
      db.execute(start + RecurrenceNames.tableName);
      db.execute(start + TransfersNames.tableName);
      db.execute(start + PlannedTransactionNames.tableName);
      db.execute(start + SettingNames.tableName);
    } catch(error){
      throw Exception('DbBase.cleanDatabase: ' + error.toString());
    }
}

await DbBase.cleanDatabase();
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
String jsondata;
jsondata = await readJson;
```

Backup and Restore. I produce a JSON file and save it in the downloads directory.
Flutter and SQLite Android device
I need to remove all existing data and read the JSON and insert as new
I have to use a Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)) or the new data is put in before the delete finishes. 
Any advice on this async problem?
so 1) use Drop table + tableName for all tables
2) insert the new data from the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem, transaction and batch

```
static Future<void> cleanDatabase() async {
    try{
      final db = await database();
      await db.transaction((txn) async {
        var batch = txn.batch();
        batch.delete(AccountNames.tableName);
        batch.delete(CategoryNames.tableName);
        batch.delete(RecurrenceNames.tableName);
        batch.delete(TransfersNames.tableName);
        batch.delete(PlannedTransactionNames.tableName);
        batch.delete(SettingNames.tableName);
        await batch.commit();
      });
    } catch(error){
      throw Exception('DbBase.cleanDatabase: ' + error.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: this will delete table itself or all records in table?

Comment: This deleted all data and tables from the database

Comment: My app needs a backup and restore so I produce a json file for backup and to restore I delete everything and create the tables and import the json file

Answer (score 1):

```
  final db = await database(); 

  db.delete(table);
```

for your code

```
  db.execute(CategoryNames.tableName);
  db.execute(RecurrenceNames.tableName);
  db.execute(TransfersNames.tableName);
  db.execute(PlannedTransactionNames.tableName);
  db.execute(SettingNames.tableName);
```